# How to get absolute path of found file using 'find' command in Linux?

Tags: shell-script, shell, command-line

I'm checking if file present with `find` command like following -

```
find ${pwd} | grep 'Test.*zip'
```

This command returns output with relative path like -

```
./ReleaseKit/Installable/Test-5.2.0.11.zip
```

Is there a way to get absolute path of found file using `find` command?

Comment: Note that `grep 'Test.*zip` would also return such files : `./ReleaseKit/Test-123-zip/file`, i.e. where not only the name of the file / directory matches, but where it appears in the whole path expression. Maybe use `-name` instead and also clarify to search for files only: `-type f`

Comment: `grep 'Test.*zip'` would also match `./ReleaseKit/Test/coat/zippers.html`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your

```
    find ${pwd} | grep 'Test.*zip'
```

is that you don't have a variable called `pwd`. So this is the same as `find | grep 'Test.*zip'`. You want to give the current directory as the starting point.

Either use `$(pwd)` or `$PWD` instead of `${pwd}`. `$(pwd)` runs the `pwd` program whilst `$PWD` uses the variable that `bash` and other POSIX shells maintains to give the current directory. Not all shells are POSIX. You should also quote the variable or the command substitution to defend against unusual characters in the directory path, s you end up with

```
    find "$PWD" | grep 'Test.*zip'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your sentence needs more parameters (path + file + action), maybe if you structure your command like this:

```
$> find {path} -iname {file} -exec {action} \;
```

Use **readlink** command to get absolute path (in Linux & OS/X)

ex.

```
$> find ./www/project/ -iname 'Test*.zip' -exec readlink -f {} \;
/opt/www/project/Test-5.2.0.11.zip
/opt/www/project/Test-5.2.0.13.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The pathnames reported by `find` will always begin with the top-level search path under which it was found.  So use an absolute path as search path:

```bsh
find "$PWD" -name 'Test*zip'
```

The `PWD` variable will hold the absolute pathname of the current directory.

GNU `find` defaults to using the current directory, `.` ("dot"), as search path if no search path is given, and this is what happens in your situation since you don't have a variable called `pwd`. This means all pathnames that `find` examines will start with a dot.  Most other implementation emit an error instead when a search path isn't given:

```
$ unset pwd
$ find $pwd
usage: find [-dHhLXx] [-f path] path ... [expression]
```